# my dialog box design is not changing no matter what i put

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make my dialog box width bigger when it displays and also have those horizontal middle borders, I guess it doesn't because my bootstrap for the site doesn't contain them, how can I fix those? This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click",".reports tr",function(){
          //alert($(this).attr("id"));

      $("#data").empty();
      $("#data").append(

              "<table class= 'table display border=3px solid black' style= 'width:700px;'>" +

"<tr>"+"<th>Months</th>"+"<th>Charges</th>"+"<th>Payments</th>"+ "</tr>"+

            "<tr>"+"<th>Janurary</th>"+"<th>"+$("#clinic" +$(this).attr("clinic")+"_charges_"+"1"+"_"+$(this).attr("year")).html()+"</th>" + "<th>"+$("#clinic" +$(this).attr("clinic")+"_payments_"+"1"+"_"+$(this).attr("year")).html()+"</th>"+"</tr>"+
            "<tr>"+"<th>Feburary</th>" +"<th>"+$("#clinic" +$(this).attr("clinic")+"_charges_"+"2"+"_"+$(this).attr("year")).html()+"</th>"+"<th>"+$("#clinic" +$(this).attr("clinic")+"_payments_"+"2"+"_"+$(this).attr("year")).html()+"</th>"+"</tr>"+
            "<tr>"+"<th>March</th>"+"<th>"+$("#clinic" +$(this).attr("clinic")+"_charges_"+"3"+"_"+$(this).attr("year")).html()+"</th>" +"<th>"+$("#clinic" +$(this).attr("clinic")+"_payments_"+"3"+"_"+$(this).attr("year")).html()+"</th>"+ "</tr>"+
            "<tr>"+"<th>April</th>"+"<th>"+$("#clinic" +$(this).attr("clinic")+"_charges_"+"4"+"_"+$(this).attr("year")).html()+"</th>" +"<th>"+$("#clinic" +$(this).attr("clinic")+"_payments_"+"4"+"_"+$(this).attr("year")).html()+"</th>"+"</tr>"+
            "<tr>"+"<th>May</th>" +"<th>"+$("#clinic" +$(this).attr("clinic")+"_charges_"+"5"+"_"+$(this).attr("year")).html()+"</th>"+"<th>"+$("#clinic" +$(this).attr("clinic")+"_payments_"+"5"+"_"+$(this).attr("year")).html()+"</th>"+"</tr>"+
            "<tr>"+"<th>June</th>"+"<th>"+$("#clinic" +$(this).attr("clinic")+"_charges_"+"6"+"_"+$(this).attr("year")).html()+"</th>" +"<th>"+$("#clinic" +$(this).attr("clinic")+"_payments_"+"6"+"_"+$(this).attr("year")).html()+"</th>"+"</tr>"+
            "<tr>"+"<th>July</th>"+"<th>"+$("#clinic" +$(this).attr("clinic")+"_charges_"+"7"+"_"+$(this).attr("year")).html()+"</th>" +"<th>"+$("#clinic" +$(this).attr("clinic")+"_payments_"+"7"+"_"+$(this).attr("year")).html()+"</th>"+ "</tr>"+
            "<tr>"+"<th>August</th>"+"<th>"+$("#clinic" +$(this).attr("clinic")+"_charges_"+"8"+"_"+$(this).attr("year")).html()+"</th>" +"<th>"+$("#clinic" +$(this).attr("clinic")+"_payments_"+"8"+"_"+$(this).attr("year")).html()+"</th>"+ "</tr>"+
            "<tr>"+"<th>September </th>"+"<th>"+$("#clinic" +$(this).attr("clinic")+"_charges_"+"9"+"_"+$(this).attr("year")).html()+"</th>" +"<th>"+$("#clinic" +$(this).attr("clinic")+"_payments_"+"9"+"_"+$(this).attr("year")).html()+"</th>"+"</tr>"+
            "<tr>"+"<th>October</th>"+"<th>"+$("#clinic" +$(this).attr("clinic")+"_charges_"+"10"+"_"+$(this).attr("year")).html()+"</th>" +"<th>"+$("#clinic" +$(this).attr("clinic")+"_payments_"+"10"+"_"+$(this).attr("year")).html()+"</th>"+"</tr>"+
            "<tr>"+ "<th>November</th>"+"<th>"+$("#clinic" +$(this).attr("clinic")+"_charges_"+"11"+"_"+$(this).attr("year")).html()+"</th>" +"<th>"+$("#clinic" +$(this).attr("clinic")+"_payments_"+"11"+"_"+$(this).attr("year")).html()+"</th>"+ "</tr>"+
            "<tr>"+"<th>December</th>"+"<th>"+$("#clinic" +$(this).attr("clinic")+"_charges_"+"12"+"_"+$(this).attr("year")).html()+"</th>" +"<th>"+$("#clinic" +$(this).attr("clinic")+"_payments_"+"12"+"_"+$(this).attr("year")).html()+"</th>"+"</tr>"+






              "</table>"


              );
      $("#data").dialog();
    });
});
```

And this is the div at the end of the page:

```
<div id="data" border="6" style= "height:50%;width:900px;background-color: #fcf8e3; font-weight: bold;font-size:14;white-space: nowrap;">

</div>
```

Comment: Do you ever consider using something like Knockout or Angular or other library so that you can have a view model?   This code could become a lot simpler/more readable with it imo. Might be overkill for what you're doing though.

Comment: ill take that into consideration, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the width of a jQuery UI Dialog with the `width` option. For example:

```
$("#data").dialog({
    width: 700
});
```

[See documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-width)

You can set a border between the first and second column using the following css:

```
.table th:first-child {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

Also, do note there is an error in your table class:
`border=3px solid black` is not a valid class.

I would suggest you move all your inline styling to a separate CSS file and use proper class names.

Comment: how can i add a title as well, i found something like {title: "Set the title to Create"}

Comment: Yes, that will work. The documentation for the `title` option [can be found here](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-title). You can combine options (for example: `{width: 700, title: 'Some title text'}`).

Comment: is there a way to put the border line in the div or table style?

Comment: If you use inline styling (using the `style=""` attribute), you can only define styling for that element. In your case, you then need to add the style attribute to all the `<th>` elements. You are better off adding a class attribute to the `<th>` elements and styling if via a separate stylesheet.